# Html Agility Pack. Load and scrape webpage

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Is this the *best* way to get a webpage when scraping?

```
HttpWebRequest oReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)oReq.GetResponse();

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

doc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
var element = doc.GetElementbyId("//start-left");
var element2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
string html = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

I've seen `HtmlWeb().Load` to get a webpage. Is that a better alternative to load and the scrape the webpage?

---

Ok i'll try that instead.

```
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
```

Now when i got my `doc` and didn't get so mutch properties. No one like `SelectSingleNode`. The only one I can use is `GetElementById`, and that works but I whant to get a class.

Do I need to do it like this?

```
var htmlBody = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
htmlBody.SelectSingleNode("//paging");
```

Comment: You can stack/append node slects too. eg:var htmlBody = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body").SelectSingleNode("//paging");

Answer (score 75):

Much easier to use HtmlWeb.

```
string Url = "http://something";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
```

Comment: can u please go through this link ..having some issue regarding HtmlWeb().Load(Url) its not loading full content of webpage.. please help me ////   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955793/why-htmlweb-loadurl-not-loading-the-page-with-full-content