# HtmlAgilityPack not finding nodes from HttpWebRequest's returned HTML

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack

I am a little new to htmlagilitypack. I want to use my HttpWebRequest which can return the html of a webpage and then parse that html with htmlagilitypack. I want to find all `div`'s with a specific class and then get the inner text of what is inside those `div`'s. This is what I have so far. My get request successfully returns webpage html:

```
Public Function mygetreq(ByVal myURL as String, ByRef thecookie As CookieContainer)
        Dim getreq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(myURL), HttpWebRequest)
        getreq.Method = "GET"
        getreq.KeepAlive = True
        getreq.CookieContainer = thecookie
        getreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"

        Dim getresponse As HttpWebResponse
        getresponse = DirectCast(getreq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)


        Dim getreqreader As New StreamReader(getresponse.GetResponseStream())
        Dim thePage = getreqreader.ReadToEnd

        'Clean up the streams and the response.
        getreqreader.Close()
        getresponse.Close()


        Return thePage
    End Function
```

This function returns the html. I then put the html into this:

```
        'The html successfully shows up in the RichTextBox
        RichTextBox1.Text = mygetreq("http://someurl.com", thecookie)

        Dim htmldoc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()

        htmldoc.LoadHtml(RichTextBox1.Text)

        Dim htmlnodes As HtmlNodeCollection
        htmlnodes = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='someClass']")


        If htmlnodes IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each node In htmlnodes
                MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText())
            Next
        End If
```

The problem is, `htmlnodes` is coming back as `null`. So the final `If Then` loop won't run. It finds nothing, but I KNOW for a fact that this `div` and `class` exists in the html page because I can see the html in the RichTextBox1:

`<div class="someClass"> This is inner text </div>`

What exactly is the problem here? Does the `htmldoc.LoadHtml` not like the type of string that the `mygetreq` returns for the page html?

Does this have anything to do with html entities? `thePage` contains `<` and `>` brackets. They are not entitied.

I also saw someone post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558149/html-agility-pack-load-and-scrape-webpage) (C#) to use the `HtmlWeb` class, but I am not sure how I would set that up. Most of my code is already written with `httpWebRequest`.

Thanks for reading and thanks for helping.

Comment: As always, I recommend using CsQuery instead of HtmlAgilityPack. Also referred by one of the SO members and once tried, I don't wanna go back.

Comment: @neolisk Never even heard of it. I just kept hearing HtmlAgilityPack. Any good sample code out there for what I am trying to do that you may have readily available? =)

Comment: Same here, I always used to recommend HtmlAgilityPack before I tried [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery). Do you know jQuery? If yes, should be an easy switch. I'll try to come with some example for you soon.

Comment: @neolisk Yes I know Jquery/Javascript. Thank you. I was just searching around for CsQuery and am mostly finding examples in C# so VB.Net examples would be awesome =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to switch, you could use [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery), something along these lines:

```
Dim q As New CQ(mygetreq("http://someurl.com", thecookie))
For Each node In q("div.someClass")
  Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText)
Next
```

You may want to add some error handling, but overall should be a good start for you.

You can add CsQuery to your project via NuGet:

```
Install-Package CsQuery
```

And don't forget to use `Imports CsQuery` at the top of your code file.

This may not directly solve your problem, but should make it easier to experiment with your data (via immediate window, for example).

Interesting read (performance comparison):

- [CsQuery Performance vs. Html Agility Pack and Fizzler](http://blog.outsharked.com/2012/06/csquery-performance-vs-fizzler.html)

Comment: Hmm still not working for me even when I tried CsQuery. I wonder if it is the way `mygetreq` returns `thepage`. It turns everything into html entities except the brackets `<` and `>`. Is the result of `thepage` OK do you think? I am doing it right?

Comment: That is, it is not finding any nodes with `div.somecClass`. It says it is empty in my error checking.

Comment: I think it may be because the `div`'s I am looking for are inside comment blocks! `<!-- -->` so it is not finding them?

Comment: @MicroR: I am not sure it can work like that with **any framework**, since putting any markup inside comment blocks invalidates it as markup. You may want to do some pre-processing, like text replace, but that may cause more issues than it solves. Why are doing this, i.e. parsing markup inside comments?

Answer (score 0):

Using htmlweb is trully a simple and good way to work with HtmlAgilityPack...here is an example:

```
Private Sub GetHtml()
    Dim HtmlWeb As New HtmlWeb
    Dim HtmlDoc As HtmlDocument
    Dim NodeCollection As HtmlNodeCollection
    Dim URL As String = ""
    HtmlDoc = HtmlWeb.Load(URL) 'Notice that i used load, and not LoadHtml
    NodeCollection=HtmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(put here your XPath)
    For Each Node As HtmlNode In NodeCollection
        If IsNothing(Node) = False Then
            MsgBox(Node.InnerText)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: But how would I set the URL for `HtmlWeb.Load()` for POST and GET requests? How can I specify existing cookies I have for `HtmlWeb`?

Comment: In your code, myURL is a parameter, so you simply put myURL inside HtmlWeb.Load(), and than,using XPath, you can choose the tags you want. Why do you want to use cookies?You said " I want to find all div's with a specific class and then get the inner text of what is inside those div's."

Comment: Because I cannot access the the URL without cookies enabled. I have preset cookies from my `httpwebrequest` that I must use to access the site.