# Get Value from source code by HttpWebResponse C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm use HttpWebResponse in c# for Response my Request 
And saves Response data(string) in StreamReader 
It's work !
But i need to Messages box for some text in StreamReader 
 Look this aera :

```
<tr><td class='left' style='width: 120px'>Country</td><td class='left'><img src='images/flags/us.png' alt='United States flag' title='United States flag'> United States (US)</td></tr>
```

this is HTML code ! 
and i want get This from it

> United States (US)

--note :
every request the : 'images/flags/us.png' And 'United States flag' It's Change to Others !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Comment: In this post i dont see Secessful answer , and this is us Webbrowser Tool not Stream data ! , Thanks for u

Comment: XmlDocument and XPaht does not work. The response could not be parsed in a XmlDocument.

Comment: Ok ! anther Idea ! , Thanks ROM

Comment: You can use a regex. It could be not so performant but it wiil work.

Comment: The answer in the linked question to parse HTML is to use the Html Agility Pack, to which you would feed your response stream, E.g. [Html Agility Pack. Load and scrape webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558149/html-agility-pack-load-and-scrape-webpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also , Html Agility Pack is the best work ! , I'm uses Regex really is
>   work!